# Troubles appending structure to file in C

Tags: c, file, io, structure, fwrite

I'm having some trouble to append a structure to a file:
OS: Ubuntu 14.04

Struct:

```
struct baris
{
    char name[30];
    char trusted[1];
    int phone;
    int id;
};
```

Func:

```
addNewBariga()
{
    char answer[30];
    struct baris new;
    while(1){
        printf("Enter new Barigas' ID please.");
        scanf("%d",&new.id);
        printf("Enter new Barigas' name please.\n");
        scanf("%s",new.name);
        printf("Enter new Barigas phone please. \n");
        scanf("%d", &new.phone);
        printf("Is Bariga trusted?\n\t[Y/N]:");
        scanf("%s",new.trusted);
        while(1)
        {
            if(strcmp(new.trusted,"Y") != 0 && strcmp(new.trusted,"y")  != 0)
            {
                printf("%s",new.trusted);
                printf("\nWrong command givven.\t\n[Y/N]:");
                scanf("%s",&new.trusted);
            }
            else
                break;
        }
        printf("Values you've entered:\n\tID:%d\n\tName: %s\n\tPhone: %d\n\tTrustworth:%s\nWould you like to proceed to saving?\n[Y/N]:\n",new.id,new.name,new.phone,new.trusted);
        scanf("%s",&answer);
        if(strcmp(answer,"Y") ==0 || strcmp(answer,"y")==0) //Process to saving
        {
            printf("saving...");
            confPtr = fopen(filePath , "ab");
            //fwrite(new.id, sizeof(new.id), 1, confPtr);
            fwrite(&new, sizeof(struct baris), 1, confPtr);
            fclose(confPtr);
            break;
        }
}
```

What I'm getting:

```
fabio\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00fab\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00fab\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00 <1\B5y\00\00\00\00\00\00\00fab\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00 \C5f\DAy\00\00\00\00\00\00\00
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The "Code Snippets" are meant for Javascript/HTML only, not for 'any' code. (It's actually an easy mistake to make due to the not-that detailed tool tip.)

Comment: @Jongware yeap, I saw that I just added it for highlighting, any other way to do it?

Comment: what is the significance of `char trusted[1];` ? why not `char trusted;` and `%c` ?

Comment: `scanf("%s",new.trusted);` `trusted` is one char. `char trusted[1];` should be `char trusted[2];`

Comment: Use the `Code Sample` button -- **{ }**

Comment: @SSC After deleting the file and running 
Id: 12 
name: fab
123
y

file output:
fabio\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00fab\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00fab\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00 <1\B5y\00\00\00\00\00\00\00fab\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00 \C5f\DAy\00\00\00\00\00\00\00

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Same with trusted[1];

Comment: "What I'm getting"????? Where exactly are you getting it? You're not reading the file anywhere in the code you provided.

Comment: @user3214998 try in the fprintf instead of fwrite.

Answer (score 1):

That output looks basically correct, what did you expect?

You're writing binary data to a binary file. Binary files are not very easy to inspect manually.

The first member of the structure, `name`, will always be 30 bytes long in the output for example.

Note as pointed out by @BLUEPIXY in a comment that this:

```
scanf("%s",new.trusted);
```

triggers undefined behavior if a non-zero length is entered, since `trusted` is only 1 character long that is consumed by the string terminator. You should increase its length, or (much better!) stop using direct `scanf()` like this and instead read a whole line of input with `fgets()` and parse it using `sscanf()`.

Also, when using functions that can fail (like `scanf()`, `sscanf()` or `fgets()`) you *must* check the return values before relying on them to have succeeded.

Comment: Outputs on printf seemed to be okay.
I'll check it out about the lengths and fgets.
thank you